# I want to obtain the ingredient display of ${\mathbf r}(\theta,z)$

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to seek Component display ${\mathbf r}(\theta,z)$

$$
   S=\{(x,y,z) : x^2+y^2+z^2=1\}.
$$

$\theta$，$z$ be real numbers  that satisfy $0<\theta<2\pi$，$-1<z<1$

Let ${\mathbf r}(\theta,z)$ be the intersection of $\{(t\,\cos\theta,\ t\,\sin\theta,\ z) : t>0\}$ with a half line passing through a point $(0,0,z)$ on the  axis    and orthogonal to the  axis and S let  ${\mathbf r}(\theta,z)$

I want to obtain the ingredient display of ${\mathbf r}(\theta,z)$

Comment: $\{(t\,\cos\theta,\ t\,\sin\theta,\ z) : t>0\}$ **is** a half line passing through $(0,0,z)$ and orthogonal to the $$ axis. What actually should it intersect?

Comment: thank you for replay. correct expression is Intersection of S and a straight line perpendicular to the z axis

Answer (score 0):

Here are some hints.

On the half line $\{(t\cos\theta,t\sin\theta,z) : t>0\}$
you have
\begin{align}
x &= t\cos\theta \tag1\\
y &= t\sin\theta \tag2\\
z &= z.\tag3
\end{align}

On the sphere you have
$$ x^2+y^2+z^2=1.\tag4$$

A point of intersection means all these equations are true at the same time.
Then Equations $(1)$ and $(2)$ give you another way to write Equation $(4)$.
What can happen then?

Comment: I guess that answer is ${\mathbf r}(\theta,z) =(\pm \sqrt{1-z^2} cos\theta, \pm \sqrt{1-z^2} sin\theta,z)$

Comment: That looks correct for the whole line. For the half line you also have the condition $t>0.$

Comment: Thank you for the easy-to-understand explanation!